# Preserving the original axis system while rotating with openGL

Tags: opengl, rotation

I'm implementing an arcball with openGL (on cpp).
Say, I have an object in the center of the axes system and i want to rotate in several times acording to the original (world) axes.
But, after the first rotation, the axes are changed and all further rotations goes wrong.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Quaternions are a good solution to 'Gimbal lock'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do the same thing myself in an OpenGL ES application, which I describe in a writeup about it [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/08/05/lessons-molecules-opengl-es).  The original crude approach read the current model view matrix and manipulated it to produce the desired effect:

```
GLfloat currentModelViewMatrix[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, currentModelViewMatrix);   
glRotatef(xRotation, currentModelViewMatrix[1], currentModelViewMatrix[5], currentModelViewMatrix[9]);
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, currentModelViewMatrix);
glRotatef(yRotation, currentModelViewMatrix[0], currentModelViewMatrix[4], currentModelViewMatrix[8]);
```

This will work, but be aware that the two `glGetFloatv()` calls will slow your rendering by halting the pipeline.  I've since replaced this code with calculations that I perform on my own internal copy of the model view matrix, then I simply write the internally manipulated model view matrix after each rotation.  This removes the need to do the expensive matrix read operations.

Answer (score 2):

Supply the object with it's own orientation axes (modelview matrix), and then multiply that by the rotation matrices.  Check Wikipedia for info on how to construct rotation matrices.

Comment: I'm using the glRotatef() function for the rotatins. What do you mean "own orientation axes"?

Comment: You are not using shaders then, sorry I should have asked.  Are you pushing/popping the matrix stack for each glRotate call?

Answer (score 1):

Add xAngle and yAngle to the current matrix.

```
Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, xAngleADD, matrix[1], matrix[5], matrix[9]);
Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, yAngleADD, matrix[0], matrix[4], matrix[8]);
gl.glMultMatrixf(matrix, 0);
```